# Fitch - Formally prove that these two premises lead to ∃x(Small(x)) using ∃ Elimination

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

1. ∃x(¬Large(x))
2. ∀x(Large(x)∨Small(x))

So far I have this:

[image]

How do I get to the goal of ∃x(Small(x))?

Am I missing something small or am I doing it completely incorrect?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: From 1) you have ¬Large(a) for some unspecified object $a$. From 2), using Universal Instantiation, you have: Large(a) ∨ Small(a). Thus, using [Disjunctive Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism#Propositional_logic) you have Small(a) from which, by Existential Introduction, you conclude with ∃xSmall(x).

Comment: Having said that, the ND proof above seems correct to me. Is there the need to specify in step 13 (the $(\exists \text E)$ step) that you are referring to the assumption in step 3?

Comment: The proof looks correct. Could it be you're missing the line numbers in step 13? Or do you need to specify that 3 is a typical disjunct? I'm not familiar with the program

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am not sure if I need to derive it in step 13 but from all the proofs that I have done in Fitch before, it's the usual practice to get the specified goal (see bottom of the screenshot)

Comment: @TenO'Four the rule next to line 13 is just me trying various options. I do not know which line to reference or what rule to select.

Comment: Try specifying 3-12 with $\exists$ elim, if that doesn't work I'm afraid you're going to need to look at the manual and see how the rule's meant to be put into the program. As I've said, the proof looks right, so the problem is finding out the particulars of how things need expressed for this particular prog

Comment: @TenO'Four didn't work but I think you Guys are right, it's more trying to figure out how the app wants it rather than a logic issue

Comment: It's one of the most annoying thing about using proof checkers :( oooh try, 1, 3-12 and the same rule

Comment: Simple: You just didn't specify where line 13 comes from. So you need to select line 1 (the existential that you are elminating) and the subproof on lines 3-12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was messing around with the below Fitch proof when I realized what is required
[image]

So my initial Fitch proof looks like this
[image]

Thank you All for Your guidance!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. It might be an idea to edit in the name of the program you're using and the specific rule you had an issue with into your initial question. That way it can help someone else with the same issue:)

Comment: Done, good idea!

Comment: Please accept your own Answer! It signals -that the issue is resolved, and prevents the system from bumping it for attention.